# Time conversion not working when passing GMT+8

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that will convert time from one time zone to another. The funcion works if I pass `EST, GMT, GMT+10, etc...` however, if I pass `GMT+8` or other GMT times the if statement never evaluates to true and is bypassed, thus returning nil and crashing the app.

```
func convertToLocalTime(fromTimeZone tzAbb: String) -> Date? {
   if let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: tzAbb) {

        let targetOffset = TimeInterval(timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
        let localOffeset = TimeInterval(TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
        return self.addingTimeInterval(targetOffset - localOffeset)

   }
 return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMT+10 represents 10 hour offset from GMT. This format needs two cyphers after the "+" sign, so basically a proper format for GMT+9 would be GMT+09. That is why your GMT+1 to GMT+9 are not being parsed correctly, but GMT+10 and above are. 
Also if you would for some reason want to specify minutes offset also, you could say in example GMT+1109.

Comment: that does fix the problem, but the new issue being that when you call `TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? ""` it will only return GMT-8 ... Is there a way to have it return with two cyphers?

Comment: Until I know a way to fix this, I just used a switch case to check if it is one cypher than change it to two